# AngularJS Google Map directive map instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I'm using http://angular-google-maps.org/ it's nice angular google maps library. But i want use map instance which is loaded not in angularjs context by something like this:

```
$scope.map = {
events: {
    tilesloaded: function (map) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.mapInstance = map;           
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Ok nice i have mapInstance and I CAN use it programmatically. But in application lifecycle this fire to late- so in other words I want to load whole directive (and get map instance) before other code- where I just wan't to use other map events.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In recently looking up ways to get the map instance from the example on the docs page, I came across this instead:

```
$scope.map.control.getGMap().
```

Make sure on your google-maps HTML markup, you have the options attribute set as `control="map.control"` and an empty object set in your `$scope.map` object.

```
$scope.map= { control : {}, ...other map options...};
```

That empty objects is filled when google map is initiated. I hope this helps and isn't too late.

Enjoy Angular!!!

Comment: How do you promisify the map loading to ensure you don't try to render markers before for instance?

Comment: I'm not sure this is best practice, but im using $timeout,0 pattern to ensure that the map is actually instantiated (not necessarily tiles loaded) before referencing map.control.

Comment: I used the following code to ensure that map was instantiated: uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function() {// your code here}). Angular-google-maps also have IsReady service in their API

Comment: @OlgaGnatenko, Please explain how you get the map object from that function.