# Set Google Maps bounds with angular-google-maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to set bounds into Google Maps instance but with no success. I'm using AngularJS and `angular-google-maps` module. My last try was:

```
<div id="map_canvas">
    <ui-gmap-google-map 
        center="map.center" 
        zoom="map.zoom"
        bounds="map.bounds"
        options="options">

        <div ng-repeat="d in devicesMarkers track by d.id">

            <ui-gmap-marker
                idkey="d.id"
                coords="d.center"
                options="d.options">
            </ui-gmap-marker>
            <ui-gmap-circle
                center="d.center"
                stroke="d.circle.stroke"
                fill="d.circle.fill"
                radius="d.circle.radius"
                visible="d.options.visible">
            </ui-gmap-circle>

        </div>

    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

In my `app.js` I wrote:

```
(...)
.controller('TaihMapController', ['$scope', '$log', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', function($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi) {
    $scope.devicesMarkers = devices;
    $scope.map = {
        center: { latitude: devices[0].center.latitude, longitude: devices[0].center.longitude },
        zoom: 12,
        bounds: {}
        // fit: true,
    };
    GoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        $log.debug(maps);
        var myBounds = new maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var k = 0; k < devices.length; k++) {
            var _tmp_position = new maps.LatLng(
                devices[k].center.latitude, 
                devices[k].center.longitude);
            myBounds.extend(_tmp_position);
        }
    $scope.map.bounds = myBounds;
    $scope.googleVersion = maps.version;
    // $scope.bounds = myBounds;
    // $scope.zoom = maps.getZoom();
    // maps.fitBounds(myBounds);
    // $scope.bounds = maps.getBounds();

});
```

The function `maps.fitBounds()` doesn't exist. I try the `$scope.map.bounds` approach, but didn't respond the way I think.

Comment: Take look at [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/master/example/example.html) github, and try to search `bounds`, there is lots of piece of code related to it.

Comment: I read this file, no success yet. This gist contains the new approach (based on the suggested file) https://gist.github.com/vitorcarvalhoml/62f804cd197572f28079 How can I set the map.center and the map.zoom based on bounds?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using angular-google-map's "markers" directive, just add the fit="true" attribute (ui-gmap-markers).

Example :

`<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options">
    <ui-gmap-markers fit="true" models="markers" coords="'self'"></ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>`

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707965

Answer (score 3):

According to [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/google-map), directives bounds is slightly different with google maps bounds. You should explicitly set `northeast` and `southwest` attributes with their own `latitude` and `longitude`.

Below should work:

```
$scope.map.bounds = {
    northeast: {
        latitude: myBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
        longitude: myBounds.getNorthEast().lng()
    },
    southwest: {
        latitude: myBounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
        longitude: myBounds.getSouthWest().lng()
    }
};
```

Comment: And place this values for example in Angular's constants - cause inside controller it stops working after the first use.

Comment: I generate the bounds based on my markers collection, and north-east/south-west values are correct. however when I set the map.bounds expression, nothing happens. the map doesn't refresh to update its view. any ideas?