# Angular-google-maps: How to get current map bounds?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I've looked all around and can't seem to find a way to get these. Basically, I'm using angular-google-maps, and am setting markers with a `<ui-gmap-markers>` tag. I'd want to get all the markers currently visible on the map, for example if a user zooms in causing some markers not to be shown, they wouldn't get selected. This very likely requires me to get the current map bounds, and I haven't found a way of doing that yet. I don't seem to have full access to google maps api, so I can't just call `map.getBounds()` or anything like that.

Comment: I think you have to do that using the Google Maps API. Have you set up Angular Google Maps correctly?

Comment: Yeh. I have `GoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {});` in my controller - the `maps` parameter doesn't seem to have the current map though as far as I can see.

Comment: Can you post an example that demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to get the map instance, and subsequently the map bounds, here: [AngularJS Google Map directive map instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786918/angularjs-google-map-directive-map-instance)

Trying to access the map instance right after google maps is loaded with `GoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {});` isn't working for me though, it hasn't added the functions to the control object at that point yet I guess - luckily for my purposes I can just call the map function when a button in the UI is pressed so it's sure to have loaded at that point, and I'm able to get the bounds. Yay!